# Fluent nHibernate CustomType for SQL2008 date and time types

Tags: fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm puzzled by some code I wrote by mistake that works...

```
        Map( x => x.StartTime )
            .Access.Property()
            .CustomType( "time" )
            .Generated.Never()
            .Column( "StartTime" )
            .Default( "(CONVERT([time],getdate(),(0)))" )
            .Nullable()
            .Not.LazyLoad();
```

For some reason it works just fine, but when I realised I meant to write CustomSqlType instead of CustomType and changed it, it stopped working... also, if I just remove the line CustomType( "time" ) it also stops working. The only way to make it work is to have it the way it is above, and I don't understand why :(

Edit: forgot to mention that on the SQL side my column is of type "time" and on the .NET side the property is of type DateTime? (nullable).

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate uses ITypes to marshal back and forth property types to column values. There are several builtin Types to use for example the `NHibernate.Type.TimeType` which has the name "time".